# Get all markers that have been added on the map with the click function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to get the coordinates for all markers I have added to the map but it only fetches the last added marker. How can I make every added markers to show in the array?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
    placeMarker(evt.latLng);
    coordinates = Array(evt.latLng + ';');
});
```

Here's how it prints now: `["(38.28993659801203, -89.6484375);"]`. I want it to print `["38.28993659801203,-89.6484375;39.9434364619742,-91.64794921875;"]`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/CZ34s/

Comment: Do you want the coordinates in one long string or as separate elements in an array? I don't quite understand why you have an array if you only want one element in it. I'd expect you either want `"38.2,-89.6;39.9,-91.6;"` (everything in one string) or `["38.2,-89.6", "39.9,-91.6;"]` (coordinate pairs are separate string elements in an array).

Comment: Good question. I want to fetch the coordinates and then split them upon `;` when I saving them into the database. I'm use to PHP's `Array()` :)

Comment: Well, I posted answers for both cases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `coordinates` outside of the click listener and `push` new coordinates onto the array:

```
var coordinates = [];

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
    placeMarker(evt.latLng);
    coordinates.push(evt.latLng.toString());
});
```

Or, if you want one long string, make `coordinates` a string and concatenate new values onto it:

```
var coordinates = "";

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
    placeMarker(evt.latLng);
    coordinates += evt.latLng.toString() + ";";
});
```

Comment: Very nice! Many thanks for the correct answer :) I'll accept it when I can